# JustMock Syntax to Moq

Tags: mocking, moq, justmock

I want to translate from JustMock syntax to MOQ :

JustMock :

```
Mock<Entities> model = new Mock<Entities>();
Mock.Arrange(() => model.Components).IgnoreInstance().ReturnsCollection(this.FakeComponent());
```

I try:

```
model.Setup(x => x.Components).Returns(this.FakeComponent());
```

but fail, Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Components` is a just a property, you'll need to use `SetupGet`:

```
model.SetupGet(x => x.Components).Returns(this.FakeComponent());
```

`Setup` is only for methods.

Comment: @Thinh, No problem.  If this resolved your question, don't forget to click the big checkbox saying so.  This helps people later on who come across this with the same question!